# Routes configuration only on a specific pages in AngularJS single page app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module, routes

I am working on a small app using Angular which has of two modules.
The target is to enable modules on different pages of an app.
For example:

```
http://domain.com/app1/#routesOfApp1
http://domain.com/app2/#routesOfApp2
```

How can I make sure that `routesOfApp1` are not available on `http://domain.com/app2/`? Is it even possible?

I know that one of the ways is to create two completely separate angular apps and load them respectively. But, I would love to keep it as a one big app, as at some point, I am planning to transition this whole thing into single page app across the board.

What are my options?

Thanks,

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Could you please give us more information about your code? What is the difference between `http://domain.com/app1/` and `http://domain.com/app2/` ? What have you tried so far?

Comment: So, `http://domain.com/app1/` & `http://domain.com/app2/` are simply two different pages of one application. Until now, I had everything rendered on the backend and I decided to start converting the app into single page app. 
There is already one ng-app on the page and I am attaching different controllers where I need them.
What I tried is creating nested apps which I load only on the pages where I need them with their own routes, but apparently it is not possible.
So, currently I am in a situation that all my routes available everywhere.

Comment: I see. As I've known, such structure is not a good solution. You will ended up with 2 apps trying to handle a single view, then they will cause bunch of conflicts. --- Depend on your requirement you can/should use difference approach like: `$stateProvider` and/or `requireJS` to manage with should be load/run on different states.

Comment: Thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you need to use requirejs. When you clicked http://domain.com/app1/routesOfApp1, routesOfApp1.html and its angularjs controller (routesOfApp1Controller.js) will load. (there is nothing for app2)

```
sampleApp.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/app1/routesOfApp1', {
                templateUrl: 'app1/routesOfApp1.html',
                controller: 'routesOfApp1Controller'
            }).
            when('/app2/routesOfApp2', {
                templateUrl: 'app2/routesOfApp2.html',
                controller: 'routesOfApp2Controller'
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/default'
            });
}]);
```

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/808213/Developing-a-Large-Scale-Application-with-a-Single