# How to run angular app in specific URL

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to run an AngularJS app in a specific URL of currently working website:

```
http:example.com/some-slug/#/angular-app-route
```

I can't remove # sign becasue of current routing in our website. How should I define routes?
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35452250/2396846) doesn't help me becasue I can't remove # and # in the middle of Angular app routes doesn't work, just like I tried this, but no success yet:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/:event-slug/#/angular-route-1', {
        templateUrl: '/templates/template-1.html',
        controller: 'route1Ctrl'
    })
    .when('/:event-slug/#/angular-route-2', {
        templateUrl: '/templates/template-2.html',
        controller: 'route1Ctr2'
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
});
```

Comment: If i understand you want to remove the # in your url ? have you try activating the HTML5 mode on your website to remove the # in your url ?

Comment: @jeremy-denis No, I don't want to remove #. actually I can not remove it. I'm looking for a way to keep it and force Angular to start its routes after #.

Comment: ok i understand now. for me as default angular have the # in his url. but i undertstand you want an url like that `domain/folder/#/....` ?

Comment: @jeremy-denis Yes exactly. I want AngularJS to ignore what's before # and just route after that.

Comment: ok unfortunately it's technically not possible but what i can advice you it's to create a subdomain `folder.yourdomain` that point to `domain/folder/...`